# CSS alignment in IE

Tags: css

Hi i created a label with some css. The label css is working fine Firefox , chrome but when i run in IE the css is not coming properly.

```
label.formInputField {width:119px; height:26px; margin:3px 0px 0 0; padding:11px 6px 0 6px; background: #dadada url('css-images/labelBG.png') 50% 50% repeat-x; float:left; display: block; font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 1.1; color:#333; text-align:right; border: 1px solid #AAAAAA; border-right: 1px solid #dadada; } 

 .div_form_textbox { width:200px; float:left; text-align:left; background-color:#E6E6E6; height:29px; margin:3px 2px 0 0; padding:5px 0 3px 5px;    border-right: 1px solid #AAAAAA;border-top: 1px solid #AAAAAA;border-bottom: 1px solid #AAAAAA; background: #e6e6e6 url('siva_images/form_input_bg.png') 50% 50% repeat-x;}

.ui-corner-left { -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius :4px;-webkit-border-top-left-radius :4px; border-bottom-left-radius: 4px; border-top-left-radius: 4px; }
            .ui-corner-right {  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius :4px;-webkit-border-top-right-radius :4px;border-bottom-right-radius: 4px; border-top-right-radius: 4px; }


<label class ="formInputField ui-corner-left" for="Pdoctor">Doctor First Name:</label>
<div class="div_form_textbox ui-corner-right">
                                    <input id="fname" name="fname" type="text" size="30" class="textbox ui-corner-all"/>
                                </div>
```

The proper output in mozilla and chrome like this
[image]

So the same thing in IE is coming like this:

[image]

The left side is the label and the right is the div inside there is a textbox. my problem 
Only half of that is coming in the label of doctors first name . Please help me to get out this issue

Comment: Its rendering fine in my IE on JSFiddle... Have you set your doctype?

Comment: yes i doctype is set as <!DOCTYPE html>

Answer (score 3):

I get that exact behaviour in IE when I [look at it in Quirks Mode](http://jsbin.com/ecamog).

You probably just need to add a valid doctype as the very first line, such as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

If you already have that, then there are other possible reasons for Quirks Mode.

Comment: I had given the first line similar to the one who have given <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: @Siva When you say "similar", could you tell us exactly what your DOCTYPE entry looks like? If it's even *slightly* wrong it'll probably trigger quirks mode. And is it definitely the very first line of your page?

Comment: @Siva: Can I have a link to your page? That way, I can quickly find the problem.

Comment: Is there any problem in css can u please find it . I had posted my css code above

Comment: A doctype may not be enough if you're viewing the page over an intranet, since IE defaults to IE7 mode for intranet pages. When you load the page, hit F12 and check the browser mode drop-down. If you need a more permanent solution, you'll have to serve the `X-UA-Compatible:IE=edge` header. Edit: I looked at thirtydot's link, and the screenshot you posted is definitely a quirks mode rendering, not IE7. So this is all irrelevant.

Comment: Hi thirtydot , Thanks for your answer . Problem sloved.

Comment: @sethobrien: That's completely true, though in this case the undesired behaviour happened only in Quirks Mode and not in any other.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 and less browsers cannot render CSS3 **-webkit** commands. Like the one you have used in css style:

```
.ui-corner-left { -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius :4px;....
```

Comment: In fact no IE browser will render `-webkit` CSS as it is not a webkit browser. However this does not address the problem the OP has, in that the document is rendering in Quirks mode.